# Can web browser read website's certificate public key via extension

Tags: javascript, ssl-certificate

I was wondering whather it is possible or not to read from web browser (via some extension) certificate public key of the website. As far as I know extensions are written in javascript so I guess the question is, is it possible to read public key of certificate using javascript?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/CertificateInfo

Comment: This is only supported by Firefox, right?

Comment: Ah yes - while Chromium does have `webRequest`, it doesn't have `getSecurityInfo()`: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/644858 - so it's Firefox-only for now.